# Send a report from the online form to the client telling all the data that he chose?

Tags: php, html

I'm a very beginner in this field 
I've made a submission form for the clients to sell some products
I get the message from the form to my email with the data that the client has entered .. 
but I want the client to get the same data to him email also with the total price of his needs depending on the email address that the clients enters in the field of [ Email address: ]

my PHP Code is:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    $email_to = "HERE I PUT MY EMAIL";
    $email_subject = "You've got a message - Online Form";


    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but ";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['face_cream']) ||
        !isset($_POST['body_cream']) ||
        !isset($_POST['body_oil']) ||
        !isset($_POST['face_wash']) ||
        !isset($_POST['breast_oil']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // required
    $face_cream = $_POST['face_cream']; // not required
    $body_cream = $_POST['body_cream']; // not required
    $body_oil = $_POST['body_oil']; // not required
    $face_wash = $_POST['face_wash']; // not required
    $breast_oil = $_POST['breast_oil']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // not required
    $agreement = $_POST['agreement']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
 if(strlen($phone) < 6) {
    $error_message .= 'The Phone Number you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
 if(strlen($agreement) < yes) {
    $error_message .= 'The agreement you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone Number: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "The chosen quantity of (Face Cream) is: ".clean_string($face_cream)."\n";
    $email_message .= "The chosen quantity of (Body Cream) is: ".clean_string($body_cream)."\n";
    $email_message .= "The chosen quantity of (Body Oil) is: ".clean_string($body_oil)."\n";
    $email_message .= "The chosen quantity of (Face Wash) is: ".clean_string($face_wash)."\n";
    $email_message .= "The chosen quantity of (Breast Oil) is: ".clean_string($breast_oil)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";



// checkbox
if(isset($_POST['agreement']) &&
   $_POST['agreement'] == 'yes')
{
    echo "You've accepted our terms and conditions.<br>";
}
else
{
    echo "You didn't agree on the Terms & Conditions.<br>";
}   



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

<?php
}
?>
```

( thanks in advance )

Comment: I wish you had summed up your question to 3 lines.

Comment: you should also replace the block starting "if(strlen($agreement) < yes)" with your checkbox check

Comment: What have you tried? What went wrong? Were there any errors? It's **not** easy for us to read 100+ lines of code. So please, save us some time asking particular questions, rather than "here's my code, why it doesn't work"? There's a [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about how to ask.

Comment: everything works .. wanna send message to the client about the data he has entered with the total price

Comment: So what's the problem? Everything obviously isn't working if you're posting your code here. Does the email not send? Is it getting caught in your client's spam folder (which is the client's issue if it is)? So what exactly is the problem? We need some details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need another @mail command, reversing the email_from and email_to

```
...... all your d**kload of code
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  // Sends to YOU
@mail($email_from, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); // Sends to the client
```

the problem with your question for future:

1. None of that code was written by you (if it was, you should have known what to do).
2. You copied the entire code because (see issue 1)
3. You didn't clearly explain what the problem was

Now. If this is what you wanted. Please click the "Accept Answer" tick to help build some good Karma